# adb pull fails with Invalid argument

Tags: android, adb, xiaomi, invalid-argument

Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro with SD inserted sd card.

`adb pull /sdcard C:\Redmi`

fails with

`adb: error: failed to create directory 'C:\Redmi\MIUI\debug_log\common\com.xiaomi.finddevice\process-com.xiaomi.finddevice:securitypush\': Invalid argument`

I believe it's because a folder with `:` cannot be created.

How to skip the directory to be copied or how to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
adb exec-out tar chf - -C /sdcard . > file.tar
```

and then extract the tar avoiding errors (you can specify what to extract from tar).

Or use `linux` or WSL to run `adb pull`.